# Sending Control-R over serial not recognized with Python/Pexpect

Tags: python, serial-port, escaping, special-characters, pexpect

I'm writing some Python code to detect the start of option ROM initialization and send the appropriate control character to enter the option ROM setup utility. This is working in most cases (control-C, control-Y, control-S...), but the character is not recognized when control-R is the key required.

I suspect this is because control-R is some sort of special control character that the terminal is interpreting and not passing on, but can't find any references to it.  I've tried prefixing it with ESC and some other control characters, but can't seem to get it recognized.  The code is simple:

```
    CONTROL_R = '\x12'
    print("Sending control-R to enter setup")
    spawn_id.send(CONTROL_R)         # send character to console
```

Any pointers or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is this "the terminal" you're expecting to intercept it? Are you spawning a shell to run the utility instead of spawning it directly?

Comment: Can you show how you're creating `spawn_id`?

Comment: I'm using pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o PubkeyAuthentication=no username@pw)

Comment: And if you run that exact command in a real terminal, does Ctrl-R work? Can you try it with [this script](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/tests/getch.py) on the SSH server?

Comment: Ctrl-R does work on a real terminal with no problem. Running your script returns 18 as expected for Ctrl-R.

Comment: Does the getch.py script show 18 both when run through pexpect and run in a real terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`spawn_id.sendcontrol('r')`

From the documentation: http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Comment: I think `sendcontrol('r')` is equivalent to `send('\x12')`, but it's worth a try, in case there's a bug in pexpect.

Answer (score 1):

I've learned from a colleague that Control-R initiates a reverse-i-search in the bash shell. This is causing the shell to eat the character before before it is handled by the option ROM code. Thanks to those of you who gave suggestions.